# Session variable persist through POST

Tags: php, variables, post

Can anyone see a bug in my code here?

Two files, one variable is set on the first page using JS and I want to pass it to the next page.

*username variable is set here, first in variable then in session*

```
username = wordOne + wordTwo + wordThree;
<?php $_SESSION['username'] = $username; ?>
```

*then I submit the form which takes user to register-form.php*

```
<form method="POST" action="register-form.php">
    <button>I like it! Make it my username.</button>
</form>
```

*when that page loads, username is grabbed and output into the input as a value*

```
<body onload="inputUsername()">


function inputUsername(){
 var username = "<?php echo isset($_POST[username])?$_POST[username]:''; ?>";
 console.log("I'm running " + username);
 document.getElementById('inputUsername').value = username;
}
```

But this doesn't work as the variable `username` is not persisting across the pages.

Comment: how do you set username variable in first page?

Comment: It's set with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see is that you are asking for `$_POST[username]` but from the form you're not passing it.I mean something like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="register-form.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>">
    <button>I like it! Make it my username.</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, You are accessing _POST variable, however you are setting _SESSION variable in your code. Therefore, the possible fix is : 
1. check for _SESSION variable in inputUsername() function OR
2. Set username in your form, so that when you submit it, it post to new page.